# Asking too many questions?

Tags: support, post-ban

I am in the top 2% this week (2016-05-11), and I'm banned from asking just because two questions a day is too much. How can two questions a day be too much?

Once I asked too many questions so I had to wait for a few days to ask more. Is there a way to check if this is the case somewhere rather than actually trying to ask a question? Shouldn't the system warn you if you are close to being put on hold because of asking too many questions?

It says "You cannot ask more than 50 questions in a 30-day period" and won't let me ask, but it never warned. I am in the top 2% this week because of my answers, and I learnt not to ask "chatty" and irrelevant questions. But two questions a day is not much. Is there no way for me to get unbanned and this just because I asked two questions a day for 3½ weeks? Two questions a day is not much, and I answered a lot of questions.

Comment: See the [complete rate-limit guide](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/164900/243725).

Comment: `Shouldn't the system warn you if you are close to being put on hold because of asking too many questions` If a warning about an upcoming throttle would change your mind about asking a question, I would wager that the question is either not that important or you haven't done enough research on it.

Comment: Jesus H Christ you have 750 asked questions and most of them are zero rated. WTH

Comment: @Magisch Maybe we can improve the system for a situation like this. I asked many old questions that still get upvoted but yes, I had to ask many times about CSS and didn't love it. Maybe we can scan the questions to see if many are similar or if they are more like irrelevant and that's why they are zero-rated. Maybe I can propose to remove some questions that are no longer relevant.

Comment: You could start by carefully researching before you post a question.

Comment: @Magisch Another change I can make is to make more issues with my issue tracker since my questions are a lot like issues with my projects that are irrelevant for other people often. Then I will have a github issue first and if I can solve it for several months and have researched it then I can ask.

Comment: You can ask as many questions as you wish, but they need to be well received in order to ask more.  If no responses, votes, etc, and posting multiple questions, this could look like question spamming.  If a question is not well received, try to modify it so that it is more clear. Often, if you can simplify it (or expand providing more insight) as required, it can garner better feedback and open up the venue for more questions. If two problems you have are related, you *may* (not always) blend them into a single question.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You should worry less about the implementation details of the question ban process and more about *improving your questions*. You have been a member here for nearly seven years and have asked over 750 questions, yet even your [most recent question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36977227/how-to-know-the-depth-of-a-path) looks like the typical junk from a newbie who hasn't bothered to read any of the rules.

- The title doesn't match the question body ("How to know the depth of a path?" vs. getting a Valgrind warning about leaked memory in an `snprintf` call).
- Important details are omitted - you say "Valgrind reports a memory leakage" but you don't bother to post the actual warning text.
- The code is not even *close* to being an [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). You should trim your code down to the *absolute* minimum that compiles and reproduces the issue you are trying to solve. In this case, we don't need any of the signal handling, option parsing, user input, etc. Get rid of it.
- There is noise in the text: "Can you help me?" (and anything similar) is not welcome. Stick to the facts of what you are trying to do, what you expect, and what is actually happening.

If you learn the rules and follow them, your questions will be better-received.

Comment: He's (sadly) not question banned, he's just hitting the actual rate limits for number of questions you can ask, because he's just asking that many questions.  He's got enough upvotes on 10-ish  old questions that he'll never get question banned, regardless of how many more hundreds of bad questions he asks.  It'd take a manual mod ban to remove such a user.  The question ban is pretty much just there for the sake of users that *exclusively* provide bad content.

Comment: Aha. I figured something fishy was going on based on the fact that his last three questions have all been posted elsewhere and migrated here and assumed there was a ban, or ban warning. Rate limiting makes sense too.

Comment: I have now proposed a new SE site for my type of questions: "Debugging". Because 98 % of my questions are about debugging.

Comment: A dedicated Stack Exchange site seems excessive. I'd rather just get myself a rubber duck for that.

Comment: Also, *good* debugging questions are a huge part of what's on-topic at StackOverflow, so there would be nothing to put on a dedicated Debugging.SE site.

Comment: The aforementioned link to the question is dead.  Perhaps next time a screenshot would be better to protect the integrity of the message, as the reasons for it's removal are clear by your message, but the actual question as an example is no longer visible.  No one likes dead links.