# What should be done about people who circumvent question-bans by asking on other sites, but the question they're asking is on-topic there?

Tags: discussion, post-ban

What should be done about people who circumvent question-bans by asking on other sites, but the question they're asking is on-topic there? How will moderators know that they're trying to circumvent the question ban, and not simply asking a question that's on-topic for another site but also happens to be on-topic for Stack Overflow?

Examples of other sites include Programmers, GameDev, and Code Review.

Comment: What's the issue there? If it's on topic for Programmers.... I mean I get where you're coming from, but at the end of the day, if it's on topic there, it's on topic there.

Comment: @Patrice The issue is that some users aren't legitimately asking questions on Programmers. They're asking questions on Programmers that they would have asked on Stack Overflow if they weren't question-banned.

Comment: and how is that an issue? Again... if the question is on topic there... it lands where it's on topic. Some questions can be asked in both, and users are free to choose where to ask them. Some people will prefer Stack for the exposure. Some people will prefer Programmers because of the different focus on the site... Some people will post where they can. As long as the content is good quality.... what's the issue?

Comment: @Patrice The only issue is that they're doing it to circumvent their question-ban on SO.

Comment: and... why is that an issue? They are question-banned here, they aren't there.... Some questions can be okay for more than one site.

Comment: In the case of [this guy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36958740/how-to-choose-types-for-a-function-prototype) Programmers will "helpfully" migrate the crap back over here and there will be absolutely no consequences. I think technically that was [rate-limit circumvention](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/322194), but almost as bad.

Comment: @AndrewMedico I was under the impression things cannot be migrated to a site where you're banned..

Comment: **Question bans block migration**. See also: http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/q/7020

Comment: I believe the circumstance reworded would be, if it is a question that would normally be valid for one niche of stackoverflow, how can it be a valid question on another section of stackoverflow.  Isn't each section designed to address it's own unique niche of issues ?  Assuming this is true, why would it be allowed on another segment, and if the user has a question ban in one part of stack, why are they not question banned elsewhere.  Possible I have misinterpreted the posters question, but this is the gist of what I feel is being asked.

Comment: @SamuelJackson there is *some* overlap between sites in the network, the OP appears to be focussing on questions that are in that overlap: `( Valid on SO ( *here* ) Valid on ANOther )`

Comment: rule on Migrating question - **you don't migrate crap**. if someone asks crap questions on one site which can be migrated to another site, regardless of a ban the question shouldn't be migrated because it's crap. otherwise if a Minecraft Modding SE site was ever established then it would be a dumping ground for Arqade to migrate all the shit error dump questions it would get (before they were made off-topic).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I don't think this is an issue. It's hard to know someone's intent, so if they ask a question that's on-topic on Programmers, moderators can't reliably tell if they were trying to circumvent a question ban on Stack Overflow. Moderators on other sites shouldn't do anything special with on-topic questions asked on their site by people who happen to be question banned on SO.